# Find the MLE of $e^{-\theta}$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Let $X_{i} \sim Poisson(\theta)$ be independent random variables. I know that the MLE of $\theta$ is the sample mean which is $\frac{\sum X_{i}}{n}$. The question asks me to find the MLE of $e^{-\theta}$. I suspect that it is to be $e^{- \overline X} = e^{- \frac{\sum X_{i}}{n}}$. But how can I determine that Maximum likelihood estimator of $e^{-\theta}$?

Comment: If $\hat\theta$ is the MLE for $\theta$ then for any $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, the MLE for $g(\theta)$ is $g(\hat\theta)$.

Comment: @Math1000 do you need your $g$ to be one-to-one injective?

Comment: I see. It is invariance property. Thank you!!